# Fog looks like sparkles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, smoke-simulation

I want to add some fog to my scene but anyway I do it, it looks weird. I want the top castle to show through the fog. But it looks like a bunch of sparkles instead of fog. I tried to do it with a smoke simulation and a semi transparent material. But the result isn't as smooth as in the pictures. Denoising just smudges the whole picture.[image]

Comment: Hello :). You can get decent results using the Principled Volume shader. The current noise and fireflies are caused by too few samples and too strong lights.

Comment: Thank you. You are right he problem was the light source. After removing the hdri and increasing the samples it looks more like I want it to.